# Failed to execute loop in NASM

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I have tried to write a simple assembly program in NASM which will print Hello World for 5 times. But the execution fails in an infinite loop printing hello world. I tried to debug the code and found that `ecx` is not properly executed and `eax` shows some other value. My code is following:

```
    section .data
    msg:    db "Hello World",10,0
    section .text
        global main
        extern printf
    main:   push ebp
        mov ebp,esp

        mov ecx,0
        mov DWORD[esp-4],0x5
        mov eax,DWORD[esp-4]
        jmp .loop
   .loop:
        push eax
        push ecx
        add esp,8

        pop ecx
        pop eax

        cmp ecx,eax
        jne .task

        jmp .done
     .task:
        push DWORD msg
        call printf
        add esp,4

        add ecx,1

        jmp .loop
      .done:
        mov esp,ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
```

Can you please help me by showing my faults.

Comment: I do not know too well the ASM, but I think you can start from http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/sample.shtml and http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/04/hello-world-nasm-linux/

Answer (score 2):

According to [X86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl), registers EAX, ECX, and EDX are caller-saved. Save them before you call `printf` and restore afterwards.

There is also a fragment in your code which I fail to understand (`add esp, 8` surrounded by push/pop, in a loop). I can provide no explanation here but if you don't understand it *either*, it might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Anton (above) is right - the unexplained `add esp,8` will trash the stack and mess everything up (and you should assume `printf` will trash the values in ECX and EAX, which you're rely on).

Here's a reference version:

```
section .data
msg:    db "Hello World",10,0
section .text
    global main
    extern printf


main:
    push dword 0x5     ;count = 5;

.next:
    push dword msg
    call printf
    add esp,4

    sub dword [esp],1  ;count--;
    jne .next          ;if(count != 0) goto next;

    add esp,4          ;Remove "count" from stack
    mov eax,0          ;Value to return from "main"
    ret
```